# Unknown error in Flash CS6 AS3 code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to build a countdown timer that uses a time that is contained in a text document called ResponseTime.txt. I am getting no error messages however it is not working. I can't find the problem.

```
{
    addEventListener('enterframe', callback_handler)
    function callback_handler(e:Event):void {
        var StartTime:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        StartTime.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        StartTime.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

        function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
            StartTime.load(new URLRequest("ResponseTime.txt"));
            var today:Date = new Date();
            var currentTime = today.getTime();
            var targetDate:Date = new Date();
            var timeLeft = StartTime.data - currentTime;
            var sec = Math.floor(timeLeft/1000);
            var min = Math.floor(sec/60);
            sec = String(sec % 60);

            if(sec.length < 2){
                sec = "0" + sec;
            }

            min = String(min % 60);

            if(min.length < 2){
                min = "0" + min;
            }

            if(timeLeft > 0 ){
                var counter:String = min + ":" + sec;
                time_txt.text = counter;
            }else{
                var newTime:String = "00:00";
                time_txt.text = newTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the load method in `onLoaded` which is the callback for when it finishes loading. So the loader never actually starts loading.

```
function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    StartTime.load(new URLRequest("ResponseTime.txt"));
}
```

Just start the load outside the callback.